# how can i make it so that a dialog box doesn't close until postexecute?

Tags: android, progress-bar

right now my progressbar dialog box can be closed if the user presses the return/back button built into the phone.....how can i disable that since I want them to wait until the download finishes, then the progressbar will do its postExecute commands

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [setCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29) using the false argument. Like this:

```
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```